# cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Last time I downloaded the certification and saved it in the following path.

```
CAfile: C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem
```

I added the path to my php.ini file like the following

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

And lastly, I restarted my xampp. But still, I am having the following error

```
cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem
CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Any one with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

is your curl.exe in the same directory as cacert.pem?

1-A solution that can help is place cacert.pem outside of Xamp directory (you may to write your new url on your php code)

2-Put it on the "C:\xampp\php directory.

Try it!

Comment: the i figured it out the problem was. when i downloaded the certification, it was only 521 lines instead of 3895 lines.